# Is this a violation? using https service in intranet?

Tags: centos, internet, ssl, privileges, https

I have CentOS 7 servers in the cloud which is offering HTTPS services.
Now this Enterprise can't use our services from the cloud, so they wanted a local intranet solution, the same as I am running in the cloud with public internet.

After doing lot of thinking, I found that I can't offer them my cloud solution unless I make everything mirrored. Then, simply  to provide the service, I decided to put the whole cloud installation in their intranet by offering them my own SSL and HTTPS official licenses too.

To do this, I made one server with CentOS 7 as a mirror of my original cloud server + DNS server using the same HTTPS configuration.

From their intranet, they can browse https://myserver.com/solutions exactly as they would have done while sitting in the real public internet.

But I am not sure if I am violating anything at all? The customer, the service provider and I agreed, that between us there are no objections. But I still question whether this does not violate SSL or HTTPS law if any.
(The SSL, HTTPS licenses are all my own assets; I myself am the owner of the cloud and intranet)

Comment: intr**a**net services/info should *not* be run in the int**e**rnet ... not even with login access control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HTTPS in an intranet is not a violation of the law.

There's no such thing as an SSL 'license' but duplicating SSL 'certificates' is also fine, although not ideal.

It could, however be against the rules of whoever issued your certificates, but that's between you and whoever issued your certificates.

Comment: @YumYumYum Can you explain what you think is "fishy" here? I read 
qasdfdsaq's answer and it seems correct to me. People copy certificates to multiple servers all the time, anyway (e.g. for high availability)

Comment: @YumYumYum: It is impossible to be any clearer. The only person who knows who issued your certificates and what you agreed with them is you.

Comment: Certificate provider is from Digicert. there terms of condition is: https://www.digicert.com/security-terms.htm